# How to obtain numerical value from Http GET method?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to obtain the numerical value for the quantity which I have inputted however I receive an error. The method which I use for getting price works, although I get this from a database. However, for quantity which I add myself(not from database) this same method doesn't work.

I tried the same `request.getParameter()`, which worked for the price

Html page

```
..............................
..............................
<td><c:out value = "£${row.price}"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="list_quantity" value="0" ></td>

<form action="order.jsp" method="GET">
 <input type = "hidden" name = "price" value = "${row.price}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="bought" value="${row.list_quantity}" />
 <input type = "submit" value = "Add to order" />
</form>
..............................
```

order.jsp page:

```
.........................
At a price of £<%= request.getParameter( "price" ) %>
You have purchased <%= request.getParameter( "list_quantity" ) %> of this item
.........................
The total price will be ???
```

`<%= request.getParameter( "list_quantity" ) %>` returns an error therefore I know this is not a way to obtain this user entered value from the previous page. Also how could I then go about manipulating this value to display a total price which multiplies the quantity being bought (list_quantity) by the price.

Comment: Have you checked to see what the request parameter has when you are trying to access it? You are sending a GET request so the parameters should be concataneted after the ? sign inside the url.

Comment: @tomerpacific Currently the url when trying to access it is e.g. http://localhost:8080/list.jsp?gift_code=100002&price=279.99&stock=7&bought=               so I can see the value is not being received from this page. How would I refer to this value as it is intially set to 0 but is changed by buttons